# mysql table linear structure

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I ask for help to group values from this table and get the second result

**id      col1       col2       col3**

 1       val1       NULL       NULL

 1       NULL       val2       NULL

 1       NULL       NULL       val3

 2       val1       NULL       NULL

 2       NULL       val2       NULL

 2       NULL       NULL       val3

**Result

 id      col1       col2       col3**

 1       val1       val2       val3

 2       val1       val2       val3

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, 
  MAX(col1) AS col1,
  MAX(col2) AS col2,
  MAX(col3) AS col3
FROM NoOneEverNamesTheirTableInSqlQuestions
GROUP BY id;
```